# Handle firestore user creation document once user authenticates with riverpod / flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, riverpod

I am new to riverpod and want to know how can I create a user document in firestore (e.g. email, sign_in_provider, name and other stuff),immediately after the user authenticates through my app using riverpod. Currently I have these 2 files 1 for authProvider

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:riverpod/riverpod.dart';

final authProvider = StreamProvider<User?>((ref) {
  return FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges();
});
```

and 1 for google sign in, which gets called when user presses a button

```
class GoogleAuthService {
  static Future<UserCredential?> signInWithGoodle() async {
    try {
      GoogleSignInAccount? gUser;
      gUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
  
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication gAuth = await gUser!.authentication;
      final OAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        idToken: gAuth.idToken,
        accessToken: gAuth.accessToken,
      );
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
      debugPrint(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('error is $e');
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Should I create another Provider to watch the first one and create the doc if it does not exist? I believe riverpod docs mention that a provider should not watch another provider in its constructor, since there will be memory leaks (or bad performance if this stream changes a lot). Could you provide some code on how to handle this pretty common case?